# Accuracy drops after changing training data with one iteration

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have been working on using LeNet in tensorflow to train and classify the german traffic signs. I have modified the LeNet first and final layers to accept both the 1 and 3 channel color images (layer 1) and the number of classes to 43
(layer 6).

```
from tensorflow.contrib.layers import flatten

def LeNet(x, inputdepth):
    # Hyperparameters
    mu = 0
    sigma = 0.1

# Solution: Layer 1: Convolutional input 32x32x3. Output = 28x28x6
conv1_W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(5,5,inputdepth,6), mean=mu, stddev=sigma))
conv1_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(6))
conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(x, conv1_W, strides = [1,1,1,1], padding='VALID') + conv1_b

# Solution: Activation
conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv1)

# Solution: Pooling. INput = 28x28x6. Output = 14x14x6
conv1 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv1, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='VALID')

# Solution: Layer 2: Convolutional Output = 10x10x16
conv2_W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape = (5,5,6,16), mean=mu, stddev=sigma))
conv2_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(16))
conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv1, conv2_W, strides = [1,1,1,1], padding='VALID') + conv2_b

# Solution: Activation
conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2)

# Solution: Pooling. Input = 10x10x16. Output = 5x5x16
conv2 = tf.nn.max_pool(conv2, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides = [1,2,2,1], padding='VALID')

# Solution: Flatten. Input = 5x5x16. Output = 400
fc0 = flatten(conv2)

# Solution: Layer 3: Full Connected. Input = 400, Output = 120
fc1_W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(400,120), mean = mu, stddev=sigma))
fc1_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(120))
fc1 = tf.matmul(fc0, fc1_W) + fc1_b

# Solution: Activation
fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1)

# Solution: Layer 4: Fully Connected. Input = 120, Output = 84
fc2_W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape = (120,84), mean=mu, stddev=sigma))
fc2_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(84))
fc2 = tf.matmul(fc1,fc2_W) + fc2_b

# Solution: Activation
fc2 = tf.nn.relu(fc2)

# Solution: Layer 5: Fully Connected. Input = 84, Output = 43
fc3_W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape=(84,43), mean=mu, stddev=sigma))
fc3_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(43))
logits = tf.matmul(fc2, fc3_W) + fc3_b

return logits
```

Since the network is configured to accept both 1 and 3 channel images, (with the `depth` argument, I am trying to use various preprocessing methods (grayscale conversion, normalization between (0,1) and scaling with [-0.5,0.5]) on the input training images and trying to evaluate the accuracy in each step. I have 6 kinds of processed data

1. Original RGB image
2. Converting to grayscale
3. Normalization of grayscale image between [0,1]
4. Scaling of grayscale image with zero mean and unit variance [-0.5,0.5]
5. Normalization on RGB image between [0,1]
6. Scaling on RGB with zero mean and unit variance [-0.5,0.5]

I wanted to create a pipeline in a loop that takes one type of preprocessed data in one iteration and performs training and validation. My code as follows

```
inputData = [
             ('RGB',X_train, X_valid),
             ('RGBNormalized', normalizedRGB_train, normalizedRGB_valid),
             ('ScaledRGB', scaledRGB_train, scaledRGB_valid),
             ('Grayscale',grayimage_train, grayimage_valid),
             ('GrayScaleNormalized',normalizedGray_train, normalizedGray_valid), 
             ('GrayScaleScaled',scaledGray_train, scaledGray_valid) 
            ]
```

the input data is a list of tuples where  in each tuple, elem[0] represents the name, elem[1] represents the training set and elem[2] represents the validation set. Now my pipeline is as follows

```
def evaluate(X_data, y_data):
    num_examples = len(X_data)
    total_accuracy = 0
    sess = tf.get_default_session()
    for offset in range(0,num_examples, BATCH_SIZE):
        batch_x, batch_y = X_data[offset:offset+BATCH_SIZE], y_data[offset:offset+BATCH_SIZE]
        accuracy = sess.run(accuracy_operation, feed_dict = {x:batch_x, y:batch_y})
        total_accuracy += (accuracy * len(batch_x))
    return total_accuracy / num_examples

import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.utils import shuffle


# Simulation Control Parameters
EPOCHS = 10
BATCH_SIZE = 128
rate = 0.0001

# Variable to store the accuracy of the model
model_performance = np.zeros((len(inputData),EPOCHS))
modelIndex = 0


for name,trainingData, validationData in inputData:
    if np.shape(trainingData)[-1] == 3:
        depth = 3
    else:
        depth = 1

    # Create tensors for input data
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 32, 32,depth))
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, (None))
    one_hot_y = tf.one_hot(y,43)

    # Tensor Operations
    logits = LeNet(x,depth)
    cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits,one_hot_y)
    loss_operation = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=rate)
    training_operation = optimizer.minimize(loss_operation)
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(logits,1), tf.argmax(one_hot_y,1))
    accuracy_operation = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))


    # Pipeline for training and evaluation
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        num_examples = len(X_train)

        print("Training on...",name,'data', 'with input size of',np.shape(trainingData))
        print()
        for i in range(EPOCHS):
            X_train, y_train = shuffle(trainingData, y_train)
            for offset in range(0, num_examples, BATCH_SIZE):
                end = offset + BATCH_SIZE
                batch_x, batch_y = X_train[offset:end], y_train[offset:end]
                sess.run(training_operation, feed_dict = {x: batch_x, y: batch_y})

            validation_accuracy = evaluate(validationData, y_valid)
            print("EPOCH {} ...".format(i+1))
            print("Validation Accuracy = {:.3f}".format(validation_accuracy))
            print()
            model_performance[modelIndex][i] = validation_accuracy

        modelIndex = modelIndex + 1

    sess.close()
```

if I try to train the network with the input data without any preprocessing, the accuracy ranges between 80-90%. However keeping the network under a loop shows strange behavior of dropper accuracy as follows

```
    Training on... RGB data with input size of (34799, 32, 32, 3)

EPOCH 1 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.038
Validation Accuracy = 0.598

EPOCH 2 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.057
Validation Accuracy = 0.055

EPOCH 3 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.057
Validation Accuracy = 0.055

EPOCH 4 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.058
Validation Accuracy = 0.054

EPOCH 5 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.057
Validation Accuracy = 0.054

Training on... RGBNormalized data with input size of (34799, 32, 32, 3)

EPOCH 1 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.054
Validation Accuracy = 0.042

EPOCH 2 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.047
Validation Accuracy = 0.049

EPOCH 3 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.054
Validation Accuracy = 0.048

EPOCH 4 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.057
Validation Accuracy = 0.054

EPOCH 5 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.054
Validation Accuracy = 0.048

Training on... ScaledRGB data with input size of (34799, 32, 32, 3)

EPOCH 1 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.056
Validation Accuracy = 0.054

EPOCH 2 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.057
Validation Accuracy = 0.054

EPOCH 3 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.057
Validation Accuracy = 0.054

EPOCH 4 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.057
Validation Accuracy = 0.055

EPOCH 5 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.057
Validation Accuracy = 0.055
Training on... Grayscale data with input size of (34799, 32, 32, 1)

EPOCH 1 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.056
Validation Accuracy = 0.051

EPOCH 2 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.058
Validation Accuracy = 0.049

EPOCH 3 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.056
Validation Accuracy = 0.049

EPOCH 4 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.055
Validation Accuracy = 0.050

EPOCH 5 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.056
Validation Accuracy = 0.050
Training on... GrayScaleNormalized data with input size of (34799, 32, 32, 1)

EPOCH 1 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.055
Validation Accuracy = 0.074

EPOCH 2 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.057
Validation Accuracy = 0.054

EPOCH 3 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.056
Validation Accuracy = 0.061

EPOCH 4 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.057
Validation Accuracy = 0.055

EPOCH 5 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.057
Validation Accuracy = 0.054

Training on... GrayScaleScaled data with input size of (34799, 32, 32, 1)

EPOCH 1 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.055
Validation Accuracy = 0.049

EPOCH 2 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.056
Validation Accuracy = 0.060

EPOCH 3 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.058
Validation Accuracy = 0.054

EPOCH 4 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.056
Validation Accuracy = 0.062

EPOCH 5 ...
Training Accuracy = 0.056
Validation Accuracy = 0.061
```

Any idea where I am making a mistake?

Comment: Could you post the same log with the training accuracy?

Comment: I modified the question to include both the training and validationa accuracies for 5 epochs of each data

Comment: It seems your network is not training at all. It's quite hard to tell where the problem is by just looking at the code, but generally tensorflow graph and training ops look correct, so I suggest the problem could be with your data. Check the way you load and shuffle the data.

Answer (score 0):

One reason is maybe that data is not shuffled properly. So the network is not properly training on the images and doesn't matter which preprocessing techniques you're working with.